# Apache Zeppelin not load libmesos.so

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere, apache-zeppelin

I'm evaluating Apache Zeppelin with the current release version [v0.5](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/releases). I have a mesos cluster with spark registered as framework, then I need configure Zeppelin to connect to the remote spark cluster on mesos.

My config in **conf/zeppelin-env.sh**  it's:

```
export MASTER=mesos://<mesos_ip>:5050
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.uri=http://<public_host_url>/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz"
```

But when I execute the boot command and run the demo notebook the log show some errors and the query don't work:

```
------ Create new SparkContext mesos://172.23.0.135:5050 -------
Failed to load native Mesos library from /usr/lib/libmesos.so
------ Create new SparkContext mesos://172.23.0.135:5050 -------
Failed to load native Mesos library from /usr/lib/libmesos.so
```

I can't find any documentation or source code about this erros message. And I don't understand the reason because I have libmesos.so on /usr/lib and when I execute separatly spark-submmit all work fine from my host.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#client-mode) you should set the `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY` and `SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI` environment variables.

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI={YOUR_SPARK_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}
```

Comment: I have your vars and the problem persist.

Comment: Are you sure you're having the `libmesos.so` on the **executor host**?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting something like below?

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=http://<public_host_url>/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
```

Comment: I use MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY because MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY it's depricated and the error persist.